# Scala - construction order and early definition syntax

Tags: scala, inheritance, syntax

I'm trying to learn Scala and thought I would begin by reading "Scala for the Impatient". There he cites the problem of construction order by using the following classes:

```
class Animal {
  val range: Int = 10
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)

}

class Ant extends Animal {
  override val range: Int = 2
}
```

and then he explained why the `env` ends up being an empty Array[Int] and proceeds to explain ways to prevent that, including the early definition syntax.

But... can't I prevent that just by doing this:

```
class Animal(val range: Int = 10) {
  val env: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](range)
  /* do animal stuff */
}

class Ant(override val range: Int = 2) extends Animal(range) {
     /* do ant stuff */
}
```

??? Why is the early definition syntax really necessary?

Comment: What happened if `Animal` class is in some other library where you don't have the control?

Comment: hummm... That's a problem. :(

Answer (score 5):

I think a better way to look at the need for early instantiation comes from mixing in traits.  With traits, you won't have a constructor that you can tweak to get around this kind of issue.  Consider this very trivial and completely unrealistic example:

```
trait Foo{
  val bar:String
  val barLength = bar.length()
}

object MyFoo extends Foo{
  val bar = "test"
}
```

As it stands right now, this code will throw a `NullPointerException` when MyFoo is created because `bar` will not yet be defined when `bar.length()` is invoked.  But if you used early initialization, and redefined `MyFoo` as:

```
object MyFoo extends {val bar = "test"} with Foo{

}
```

then everything works just fine.

Comment: HUM! This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks.